# iOS In App purchase hosted content download

Tags: ios, download, in-app-purchase, hosting

Suppose I have an App TestApp 1.0 - I have added an In-App "A" version 1.0 which is a non-consumable product with Hosted Content. User1 downloads the app version 1.0 but does not buy In-App "A".

Now I update the app to version 1.1 - I also update Hosted Content for In-App "A" to 1.1

Now User1 still has app version 1.0 - now he purchases In-App "A" . Which In-App Hosted Content will he get from iTunes server -> 1.0 or 1.1

Answer (score 0):

When you are requesting the product using `SKProductsRequest`, the application will return `SKProductsResponse`. This response contains the array of all the valid products.

It is up to you how you have handled the product array. The best way to do is as follows:

```
for(SKProduct *product in skproductResponse.products)
{
    if(product.productIdentifier == YOUR_IDENTIFIER)
    {
            //Do what ever you want with app version or anything...
    }

}
```

Comment: Do we have the option to download an older version of In-App Hosted Content?

Comment: Yes. He can download older content as well. I mean if you have separate product for both, you can download older content as well.

Comment: Suppose - this is the app id -> com.test.app

This is the in-app id -> com.test.app.inappA